# Onclick submit, in a form, get inputbox value into variable and output it into another inputbox

Tags: php, forms, variables, input, submit

I am developping a job appliance form, that outputs its results into a CRM (Customer Relationship Management).

My problem is that my client wants the fields "Street Adress, Postal Code and locality" outputted all together in one single field in CRM, after inputted in different fields on the form.

So i thought i should use php for when the user clicks on submit it gets the value of each one of the fields and inputs it into an hidden field i created.
for some reson, as i am not a php expert, it isn't working.
It is really not outputting any value into the CRM

this is what i've got so far:

```
<form action="https://service.capsulecrm.com/service/newlead" method="post">

    <input name="morada" id="morada" maxlength="255" title="" style="border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; border-color: #cccccc; position: absolute; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; width: 220px; height: 20px; font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 11px; color: #333333; background-color: #ffffff; z-index: 1; left: 189px; top: 397px;" value="" type="text">

    <input name="postal" id="postal" maxlength="255" title="" style="border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; border-color: #cccccc; position: absolute; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; width: 220px; height: 20px; font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 11px; color: #333333; background-color: #ffffff; z-index: 1; left: 189px; top: 437px;" value="" type="text">

    <input name="local" id="local" maxlength="255" title="" style="border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; border-color: #cccccc; position: absolute; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; width: 220px; height: 20px; font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 11px; color: #333333; background-color: #ffffff; z-index: 1; left: 189px; top: 467px;" value="" type="text">


    <?php if ($_POST['submit']) {

    $addressmorada = $_POST['morada'];
    $addresspostal = $_POST['postal'];
    $addresslocal = $_POST['local'];

    echo "<input type='hidden' name='STREET' value='".$addressmorada. " " .$addresspostal. " " .$addresslocal."' />";

    }

    ?>

<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" style="
    border-style: none; border-width: 0px; border-color: #888888; position: absolute; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; width: 93px; height: 33px; z-index: 1; 
    left: 433px; top: 1773px;
    text-indent: 99999999999999px;
    background: green;
    cursor: pointer;
">


</form>
```

I will try to explain my PHP code,

1. the if statement it's calling the function on submit.
2. the variables get the different input values.
3. I echo an input field type hidden, calling the variables, so that all the information is outputted into the CRM in one single field

I think the major problem may be on number 3! i'l apreciate any help.
Sory if my english is bad, it's not my mother language.

Comment: Where are the `form` and the `submit` elements ?

Comment: How about a textarea to collect all three pieces of data together?

Comment: sory i didn't think it was important, edited with form tag and submt button

Comment: DevlshOne, that is not a possible option, thank you

Comment: Why this isn't working? What's the problem?

Comment: The problem is that it isn't outputting any variable content

Comment: @BrunoM93 See Rabin's answer.

Comment: @BrunoM93 See `Samuel Cook's` answer also. It's always best to use `if (isset($_POST['submit']))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're confusing server-side and client-side code. Here's a simple explanation, though you should document yourself more about HTTP and the way web servers work:

- when a user A requests a page, a HTTP request is sent to the server
- this request is handled by a web server B
- according to some rules (file extension, file location, ...), the web server can decide to simply fetch the file and send it to the client A (e.g. for a plain HTML file), or run it through a (PHP) interpreter first and then send the *result* to the client.
- in any case, the client A receives only the HTML: the PHP has already been executed by B at this point.

So the user requests the page with the form. At this point he didn't submit anything yet, so the PHP interpreter gets nothing in `$_POST` and the hidden input is empty.

The user fills the form and submit it. That triggers a new HTTP request with the data. But of course the hidden input is still empty, and will never get filled because the PHP has *already* been executed (and won't ever be client-side).

What you need to do is either

- modify the target script (https://service.capsulecrm.com/service/newlead) if you have access to it, in order to join the fields together
- if you can't, add an intermediate PHP script which is the target of the form, join the fields together and send a HTTP request itself (e.g. with curl) to newlead
- or if you don't want to spend too much time on that, use **client-side** code, that is Javascript, to fill the hidden input. However you can't be sure the form will be submitted correctly (the user can choose to disable Javascript, or the client may not handle it at all: this is common for Braille devices).

Comment: you are absolutely right, i think i will try some javascript to do this!

Answer (score 2):

two issues:

1,

```
   if ($_POST['submit'])
```

will throw an error: `Notice: Undefined index: submit in ...` if there is no `$_POST` data.

it should be changed to

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
```

2, `$_POST['submit']` will never occur as there is no `name` attribute called `submit`. You should add this to your "submit" button:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" style="[STYLES_HERE]">
```

Comment: I tried the OP's code with Rabi's answer, leaving `if ($_POST['submit'])` intact, and it worked, even with no data entered. I did not get an `Undefined index...` error. FF v22 - although `if (isset($_POST['submit']))` is better practice.

Comment: I run strict errors when testing code. Are you sure you have everything on?

Comment: What do you mean by "everything on"?

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL);` which covers strict | notice | deprecated | warning | parse etc.

Comment: Ok, you're right Samuel. I didn't have it on and it did in fact show the error message. However, that shouldn't stop the code from executing. But you are definitely right and I will make it a point to use that from hereonin, thanks. +1 on my part, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a name for you button right.

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name = "submit" >
```

You have
     if ($_POST['submit']).

So the name of the button should be submit. Otherwise it will never go in your if statement. 
For debugging purpose 
Try just printing all the values in the if statement. Its helpful.

Comment: Slight error though `<input type="submit" value="Submit" name = "submit"  ">` Take out the last `"` as in `<input type="submit" value="Submit" name = "submit">` ;-)

Comment: the last " is from style="  ">
I'll try your suggestion, thank you.

Comment: @BrunoM93 I tested your code with Rabin's answer, and I got the output successfully printed on screen. Yet I think it could stand for a bit more work though, which I can't do myself. Too extensive.

Comment: @BrunoM93 Just a suggestion. If you are redirecting your form in the samefile. You can just leave the action empty [ action = ""]. Makes it less error prone, Since you have a long URL